# MSSQL Query not returned strings with accented characters in a custom Drupal 7 module

Tags: php, sql, drupal, sql-server-2012, drupal-7

```
$queryStr = "SELECT tblContacts.IDENT, tblContacts.Date_Entered, tblContacts.Date_Updated, tblContacts.Title, tblContacts.Forename, tblContacts.Surname FROM tblContacts
    WHERE tblContacts.ID >= '$from'
    AND tblContacts.ID <= '$to';";

    $query = mssql_query($queryStr);

dpm(mssql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

The above code is not returning any text values that have got accented characters in them. This is being run from a custom lightweight Drupal 7 module using PHP 5.5.9.

When I run this code in a regular .php file, it get's the values fine. The SQL server is 2012, but from testing with other SQL server versions, it still does not work. I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Database API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database) and use db_query()

Comment: I would but the target database is a Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: Oh, and it's not the database Drupal is using. That's a MySQL one.